# Knife Project mesh without faces

Tags: modeling, edges, knife-tool

Is there a way to cut these dome shaped edges with another mesh/curve?

[image]

Knife project, Bisect and Booleans only work with meshes that have faces.

Comment: No, isnt from my knowledge. For co-planar edges you can use Tiny CAD addon, but it is not your situation. For this specific case I would use Bridge loop to generate faces, use Intersect (Knife), after operation delete previously generated "bridge" face loops.

Comment: why do you need edges and not faces on the object?

Comment: I'll try to set all Z coords to 0 to make them coplanar for TinyCad, then reset to old value. After that I'll try to set some temp faces and delete all new edges and faces after that, if that's easily possible, don't know yet.